# Using Redis with Ruby on Rails

Tags: ruby-on-rails, redis

I have developed a Rails application, where I have used one model, student. The number of students is fairly large, about 10,000. So while I am using a json call like this:

`students.json?subject_id=4`

or doing some query like this:

`@student = Student.all(:subject_id => 4)`

It is taking fair amount of time, from 2 to 4 seconds. So I want to use Redis here to store students in Redis because I think it will reduce this searching time to the order of miliseconds.

Actually I have never used Redis before. I understand that I have to rewrite the student model and controller to use Redis. Being an absolute beginner in Redis, I am asking how will I approach the problem. Also if my understanding is wrong, please clarify. Thanks in advance.

Comment: You can try to use https://github.com/soveran/ohm as ODM to replace ActiveRecord.

Comment: But I am using DataMapper here as ORM, so can you suggest me how to use it with Redis or is it impossible?

Comment: Did you add index on subject_id field? It could speed up your queries.

Comment: Yes I have added, even after that it is taking that much time.

Answer (score 0):

10,000 record isn't that much, i think you should figure out whether the problem is in your db design. Look for the db query make by rails in the development log or the console, and use "explain" of sql and see whether an index is used.